# Design level query regarding Database access layer implementation for Java applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

**Objective :** 
I want to design a DAO layer for may application , which will be used by web-applications and core java programs also.

1. Fist is it a good approach to have webservice for each database operation
   (like : `http://sometomcatappurl//insertEmp,updateEmp`)
   I am planning to configure connection pool in context.xml of tomcat
   Access the data-source using spring , perform operation using jdbc template
   I will use batch update in few places where i need to process requests in bulk.
2. The above URL will be call from various internal applications to communicate with database.
3. Per day requests expected 10-Million Inserts , 20-Million Updates, 20-Million selects.

**Concern:** Java, Tomcat , DB oracle and mysql are the technology constraints -

Which approach will be the fastest and salable way dealing with huge database operators.

Can spring handle huge requests, is it a good approach to have a web-service to perform database operations.

**Note:** I don't want to bloat my applications by writing database connection every where by accessing from a properties file, that is the reason going for context declaration with pool size.

Comment: Thank you Deinum, I wanted make the questions more readable, will take care from next time.

Answer (score 0):

A webservice works best for coarse grained transactions.  If webservice is just a wrapper around a JDBC connection, you have only added overhead to the process.  The webservice should represent a complete logical unit of work that either all succeeds or all fails.

In my experience, performance is 95% about managing the database.  Spring adds overheads measured in nanoseconds per transaction, but using a column in a query on a table with a well tuned index that is not necessary can add 10 milliseconds to a transaction.

I am not sure what you consider "huge database operators".  The workload you describe appears pretty mundane to me.

A good design that I have seen used to improve the scalability of systems is to put the business transaction processing (those that resolve to database inserts and updates) behind a webservice layer on dedicated hardware, which has the DAO and DSO layers embedded with in it.  However, database selects for user display were run directly against the database to minimize the overheads.  The DB server was scaled to handle the workload, running on a high SAN appliance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, 
Having web-service is added layer but i want to make all DB calls more accessible across other core java apps.Reg huge load the logic is to handle msg service,which will have huge traffic in number of messages,For each msg i may have to create customer and other logic to run.Same logic is used by across core java prgs that's why i want a web-service, which is easy to install even in different m/c and just access the url for db operation.
Reg spring i don't know, whether to use it or not with this scale of operation, i need your expert advice here.

Comment: It would be a mistake to call me an expert in spring.  However, spring was a hard sell for me for a long time, largely because every time I set out to build a demo project  to "use spring", I ended up factoring Spring right out.  When I finally made the conceptual leap to understanding Spring, I understood that factoring it out was using it correctly.  Spring (and the ecosystem around it) exists to free you from the repetitive drudge work so you can focus on the business logic.  In practice, on projects of similar characteristics, I wouldn't do it any other way.